# how can i get rid of a zombie channel in LND?

Tags: full-node, lightning-network-daemon, transaction-id, lncli, ln-closing-channels

**My LN-Node**: 023bf99414b3e93ab7463ce60f44cd691f8be3c1ae33a2015fe784c85c36e770cf
bitcoind 0.17.1 // LND 0.5.2-beta commit=v0.5.2-beta-rc7

**Channel:** 598078250466476032

**Problem:** lncli feereport returns:
 *rpc error: code = Unknown desc = no policy for outgoing channel*

**edit:** 
***more of the same?***
lncli fwdinghistory returns:

*{

    "forwarding_events": [

    ],

    "last_offset_index": 0

}*

***related?***
**trying to edit a recent channels policy..**

*"channel_id": "620981077780267008",

    "chan_point": "e388cce2698c0406985af2fce27ee47c5f02b04e8fbda0523975b71246e66d77:0",

    "last_update": 1551629972,

    "node1_pub": "023bf99414b3e93ab7463ce60f44cd691f8be3c1ae33a2015fe784c85c36e770cf",
    "node2_pub":

 "03efccf2c383d7bf340da9a3f02e2c23104a0e4fe8ac1a880c8e2dc92fbdacd9df",

    "capacity": "500000",

    "node1_policy": {

        "time_lock_delta": 144,

        "min_htlc": "0",

        "fee_base_msat": "1000",

        "fee_rate_milli_msat": "1",

        "disabled": false

    },

    "node2_policy": {

        "time_lock_delta": 14,

        "min_htlc": "1000",

        "fee_base_msat": "485",

        "fee_rate_milli_msat": "1",

        "disabled": false*

lncli updatechanpolicy --base_fee_msat 419 --fee_rate 0.000001 --time_lock_delta 14 --chan_point e388cce2698c0406985af2fce27ee47c5f02b04e8fbda0523975b71246e66d77:0

*[lncli] rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Channel from self node has no policy*

Comment: as mentioned in the mail I send you it looks like the funding tx of the channel was already spend: https://www.smartbit.com.au/tx/2a00c8d2e392cbf20f9175f2ebb72dd1f8d522547cf5b3d01725446a08776e59 so the channel is closed

Comment: Also the command to remove a channel from the DB has not been added yet but should be released in 0.6 IIRC

Comment: yes, the channel is closed. 
i want to purge it from the DB to fetch the feereport.
i guess 0.6 will fix this.
Thank you for your input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this was fixed in version 0.6-beta

Comment: This problem still appears in lnd 0.9.0-beta.